# Tensorflow network too large for GPU memory

Tags: tensorflow

I have a rather large network, and my GPU is running out of memory. It isn't a bug in any of the code, the network itself is simply too large to fit into memory. I've even tried the GPU config recommendations [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/using_gpu/index.html).

For example, I've tried both of the `gpu_options` below...

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions()
config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
# config.optimizer_options.opt_level = 2
# config.graph_options.enable_recv_scheduling = True
# config.graph_options.build_cost_model = 1
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.1
```

But I'm still running out of memory. I have been informed by GitHub user @girving [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3751) that Tensorflow doesn't handle Memory overflow (which makes no sense to me why they wouldn't implement this).

However, he also claimed there are workarounds. I can't find any support of anyone who has had to implement a workaround. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Can I implement Queuing somehow?

For reference, here is some code... the program runs out of memory at the time of `sess(init)`

```
#Kendall Weihe
#This is a CNN that handles 3D data
#Adjust network parameters below, also adjust data directory

import tensorflow as tf
import pdb
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell
from tensorflow.contrib.grid_rnn.python.ops import grid_rnn_cell
from tensorflow.tensorflow.scroll import scroll_data

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_iters = 1000000
batch_size = 1
display_step = 1

# Network Parameters
n_images = 100
n_input_x = 396 # Input image x-dimension
n_input_y = 396 # Input image y-dimension
n_input_z = 5
n_hidden = 128
n_classes = 2 # Binary classification -- on a surface or not
n_output = n_input_x * n_classes

dropout = 0.75 # Dropout, probability to keep units

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input_z, n_input_x, n_input_y])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input_z, n_input_x, n_input_y, n_classes], name="ground_truth")
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) #dropout (keep probability)

def input_data():
    data = np.empty((n_images, n_input_x, n_input_y))
    temp = []
    for i in range(n_images):
        filename = "/home/volcart/Documents/Data/input_crops/cropped00" + str(i) + ".tif"
        im = Image.open(path)
        imarray = np.array(im)
        temp.append(imarray)

    for i in range(n_images):
        for j in range(n_input_x):
            for k in range(n_input_y):
                data[i][j][k] = temp[i][j][k]

    return data

# Create some wrappers for simplicity
def conv3d(x, W, b, strides=1):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv3d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def maxpool3d(x, k=2):
    # MaxPool2D wrapper
    return tf.nn.max_pool3d(x, ksize=[1, k, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')

def deconv3d(prev_layer, w, b, output_shape, strides):
    # Deconv layer
    deconv = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(prev_layer, w, output_shape=output_shape, strides=strides, padding="VALID")
    deconv = tf.nn.bias_add(deconv, b)
    deconv = tf.nn.relu(deconv)
    return deconv

# Create model
def conv_net(x, weights, biases, dropout):
    # Reshape input picture
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, n_input_z, n_input_x, n_input_y, 1])

    with tf.name_scope("conv1") as scope:
    # Convolution Layer
        conv1 = conv3d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
        # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
        #conv1 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv1)
        conv1 = maxpool3d(conv1, k=2)

    # Convolution Layer
    with tf.name_scope("conv2") as scope:
        conv2 = conv3d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
        # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
        # conv2 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv2)
        conv2 = maxpool3d(conv2, k=2)

    # Convolution Layer
    with tf.name_scope("conv3") as scope:
        conv3 = conv3d(conv2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])
        # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
        # conv3 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv3)
        conv3 = maxpool3d(conv3, k=2)

    # pdb.set_trace()

    temp_batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0] #batch_size shape
    with tf.name_scope("deconv1") as scope:
        output_shape = [temp_batch_size, 2, n_input_x / 4, n_input_y / 4, 16]
        strides = [1,2,2,2,1]
        #conv4 = deconv3d(conv3, weights['wdc1'], biases['bdc1'], output_shape, strides)
        # conv4 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv4)
        conv4 = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(conv3, weights['wdc1'], output_shape=output_shape, strides=strides, padding="SAME")
        conv4 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv4, biases['bdc1'])
        conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv4)

    with tf.name_scope("deconv2") as scope:
        output_shape = [temp_batch_size, 3, n_input_x / 2, n_input_y / 2, 8]
        strides = [1,1,2,2,1]
        conv5 = deconv3d(conv4, weights['wdc2'], biases['bdc2'], output_shape, strides)
        # conv5 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(conv5)

    with tf.name_scope("deconv3") as scope:
        output_shape = [temp_batch_size, n_input_z, n_input_x, n_input_y, 1]
        #this time don't use ReLu -- since output layer
        conv6 = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(conv5, weights['wdc3'], output_shape=output_shape, strides=[1,1,2,2,1], padding="VALID")
        conv6 = tf.nn.bias_add(conv6, biases['bdc3'])
        conv6 = tf.nn.dropout(conv6, dropout)
        # conv6 = tf.nn.relu(conv6)


    # pdb.set_trace()

    x = tf.reshape(conv6, [-1, n_input_x])
    x = tf.split(0, n_input_y * n_input_z, x)

    lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    # lstm_cell = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * n_hidden, state_is_tuple=True)
    lstm_cell = rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell, output_keep_prob=0.75)
    outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)


    output = []
    for i in xrange(n_input_y * n_input_z):
        output.append(tf.matmul(outputs[i], lstm_weights[i]) + lstm_biases[i])

    return output

weights = {
    # 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs
    'wc1' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2, 2, 1, 8])),
    # 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
    'wc2' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2, 2, 8, 16])),
    # 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
    'wc3' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2, 2, 16, 32])),

    'wdc1' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2, 2, 16, 32])),

    'wdc2' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2, 2, 8, 16])),

    'wdc3' : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 2, 2, 1, 8])),
}

biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8])),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16])),
    'bc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bdc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16])),
    'bdc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8])),
    'bdc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1])),
}

lstm_weights = {}
lstm_biases = {}

for i in xrange(n_input_y * n_input_z):
    lstm_weights[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_output]))
    lstm_biases[i] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_output]))

# Construct model
with tf.name_scope("net") as scope:
    print "Building network..."
    pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases, keep_prob)
    print "Network built!"

    # pdb.set_trace()
    pred = tf.transpose(tf.pack(pred),[1,0,2])
    pred = tf.reshape(pred, [-1, n_input_z, n_input_x, n_input_y, n_classes])
    # Reshape for cost function
    temp_pred = tf.reshape(pred, [-1, n_classes])
    temp_y = tf.reshape(y, [-1, n_classes])

with tf.name_scope("loss") as scope:
    # cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
    cost = (tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(temp_pred, temp_y))

with tf.name_scope("opt") as scope:
    print "Initializing optimizer..."
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
    print "optimizer initialized!"

# pdb.set_trace()

# Evaluate model
with tf.name_scope("acc") as scope:
    # accuracy is the difference between prediction and ground truth matrices
    correct_pred = tf.equal(0,tf.cast(tf.sub(tf.nn.sigmoid(temp_pred),temp_y), tf.int32))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

with tf.name_scope("prediction-node") as scope:
    prediction_node = tf.nn.sigmoid(temp_pred)

# Initializing the variables
with tf.name_scope("initialize-and-config") as scope:
    print "Initializing variables & configuring..."
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions()
    config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    # config.optimizer_options.opt_level = 2
    # config.graph_options.enable_recv_scheduling = True
    # config.graph_options.build_cost_model = 1
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.1
    print "Variables and configurations initialized!"

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    print "Initializing session..."
    sess.run(init)
    print "Session initialized!"

    print "Restoring session..."
    saver.restore(sess, "/home/volcart/Documents/3D-CNN-2D-LSTM-reg-model/model.ckpt")
    print "Session restored!"

    tf.get_default_graph().finalize()
    # Import data
    print "Importing data..."
    data = input_data()
    print "Data imported!"

    # Keep training until reach max iterations
    for i in range(n_images):

        print "Prediction image number -- " + str(i)

        temp = []
        for j in range(n_input_z):
            temp.append(data[j,:,:])

        temp = np.asarray(temp)
        temp = temp.reshape((1, n_input_z, n_input_x, n_input_y))
        prediction = sess.run(prediction_node, feed_dict={x: temp, keep_prob: 1.0})

        prediction = prediction.reshape((n_input_x, n_input_y, n_classes))

        temp_arr1 = np.empty((n_input_x, n_input_y))
        for i in xrange(n_input_x):
            for j in xrange(n_input_y):
                if l == 0:
                    temp_arr1[i][j] = prediction[i][j][0]

        csv_file = "/home/volcart/Documents/3D-CNN-2D-LSTM-pred/3D-CNN-2D-LSTM-step-" + str(i) + ".csv"
        np.savetxt(csv_file, temp_arr1, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Can you figure out how much memory your parameters and activations need?

Comment: If your parameters are too big to fit, there s not much you can do. If it's the activations, there may be tricks to decrease memory usage

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I did the math on the number of weights in the LSTM (assuming 4B weight values), and it came out to roughly 5GB, so it's safe to say that the network itself is simply too large. Turns out I don't actually need a network of this size, so I'm just going to cut the size down.

Comment: @Kendall Weihe How to cut the size down ?